# Pythagorean theorem in linear regression using matrix notation

Tags: linear-algebra, regression

I am reading online scribe notes on linear regression and I am being quite confused (since did not do linear algebra for a while) on how Pythagorean theorem is being applied here:
[image]

First of all I am confused of what "cost" is and then how we get from

$$\arg min_x ||A(x-x') - bb'||_2^2  $$ to

$$\arg min_x ||A(x-x')||_2^2 - ||b'||_2^2  $$ ? E.g I need some intuition and mathematical explanation of what is happening here and how Pythagorean theorem is used in vector space.

Also why $$\arg min_x ||Ax - b||_2 \equiv \arg min_x ||Ax - b||_2^2 $$?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cost is $\arg\min_x ||Ax-b||_2^2$, and one aims at finding a minimizer $x$.

The "Pythagorean theorem" refers to the fact that

$$||x+y||_2^2 = ||x||_2^2 + ||y||_2^2$$ whenever $x \perp y$.

In general (Hilbert spaces over $\Bbb{C}$), we have

\begin{align}
||Ax-b||_2^2 &= \langle A(x-x') - b', A(x-x') - b' \rangle \\
&= \langle A(x-x'), A(x-x')\rangle - 2\mathop{{\rm Re}}(\langle A(x-x'), b'\rangle) + \langle b',b'\rangle \\
&= ||A(x-x')||_2^2 + 0 + ||b'||_2^2 \tag{$b' \perp A(x-x')$} \\
&= ||A(x-x')||_2^2 + ||b'||_2^2
\end{align}

To address that last problem, observe that for any strictly increasing function $f$, $x < y \iff f(x) < f(y)$ *by defintion*, so $f(p(x))< f(p(y)) \iff p(x) < p(y)$.  Take $f(x) = x^2$ on $[0,\infty)$ to finish the argument.

Comment: I am not very clear on this math notation. What is x' or b'? What is Re? )

Comment: I use $x'$ and $b'$ as in your notes.  $Re$ means real part, but that's irrelevant to this question since you're dealing with real-valued data.  I put this so that it's also true in Hilbert spaces.

Comment: one more question . Why b  = Ax' + b'  must be orthogonal  to col space of A?

Comment: @YohanRoth Sorry for late reply.  I've made a typo.  It should be $b'$ instead, as in the notes.